# Attempted to inject an HttpServletRequest before it has been initialized

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, deltaspike

I have an ear project generated using maven javaee6 artifact and have the following dependencies:

```
ejb/pom.xml
   -seam-security
   --solder-xxx

war/pom.xml
   -ejb
   *Then I excluded seam-security
```

In ejb project, I have a bean that uses `org.jboss.solder.servlet.http.RequestParam`, example if the page is edit or not:

```
@Inject
@RequestParam()
private Instance<String> edit;
```

But the problem is, it's throwing the above error: `"Attempted to inject an HttpServletRequest before it has been initialized"`

Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that stuff was ever really tested well, and if it's inside an ear I really have no idea if it will work correctly or not.

Comment: I see, I'm really not able to work around this issue. I hate to use f:viewParam because injection is much more convenient in my case. But note that it works on a WAR project.

Answer (score 0):

EJBs operate outside of HTTP requests.  The ability to inject something from an HTTP request into an EJB doesn't make sense.

If this were a CDI Request Scoped object, it would make sense.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I'm not injecting HTTP Request to an EJB, but to a ConversationScoped bean inside the EJB project. Not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: and the conversation scoped object is injected directly to your UI, or referenced directly?

Comment: hi John, it is injected directly to the UI. I was able to access FacesContext class in EJB by adding it to the jboss deployment descriptor but still I have this error. So I think it's not possible.

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but try to create a CDI extension that installs the conversation scoped bean during process annotated type phase within your WAR.